# Virtualbox not working after Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox, 17.10

After upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 my VirtualBox wont start:

```
$ VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.13.0-16-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.1.18r114002
```

---

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxdrv.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxdrv.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxballoonctrl-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxballoonctrl-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxautostart-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxautostart-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxweb-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service.
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

**/var/log/vbox-install.log** :

```
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build -j8 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
```

What would be my course of action?
Thank you

Comment: You can start with installation of `dkms`, `linux-image-generic`, `linux-headers-generic` packages.

Comment: @N0rbert I used `sudo apt-get install ` and all these packages were already the newest version.

Comment: What kernel version do you use now? Post `uname -r`.

Comment: @N0rbert `4.13.0-16-generic`

Comment: `sudo dkms -k 4.13.0-16-generic` may help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrading to latest version solved the problem:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/virtualbox-reached-5-2-major-release-how-to-install/

Comment: it didn't work in my case

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-lowlatency linux-headers-4.13.0-16-lowlatency linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic` and reinstall Virtualbox or virtualbox-dkms

Answer (score 0):

I have installed latest VirtualBox(5.2.8 ATM) on Ubuntu 17.10 and it did not launch.

Solution:

```
sudo apt install -f
```